# Second nvme missing in /dev/ after kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, ssd, arch-linux, linux-kernel, nvme

I have been pushing back my kernel upgrades on my arch machine because after upgrading from 5.14.9 my secondary nvme is not populated into /dev/ anymore.
But I want to tackles this now, hopefully with your help!

```
uname -a
Linux ryarch 6.1.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 09 Feb 2023 20:06:08 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have 2 ssd(01:1TiB, 04:0.5TiB):

```
❯ lspci |grep Samsung
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

But lsbkl shows nothing of 01:00.0:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 465.3G  0 part /
```

DMESG is empty regarding 01:00.0, the second one is set up just fine, running my / .

When booting my nvme ssd should show up in /dev.
I have not been able to find errors regarding the nvme.

When downgrading back to 5.14.9 everything works as expected.